# How do I implement install yum package if is available using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to implement this logic in ansible: install a named yum package if is available, do not fail if the package does not exist in enabled repos, fail only if installation fails.

Comment: I guess you can craft `failed_when` statement to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Just do a search first, and only install if it returns any results:

```
- hosts: host
  tasks:
    - name: Search for package
      yum:
        list: <package_name>
      register: package_list

    - name: Install package
      yum:
        name: <package_name>
        state: present
      become: yes
      when: 'package_list.results | length != 0'
```

replace `<package_name>` with the package you are interested in.

Here is an alternative with `failed_when`, but it's quite hacky as it relies on the message returned by yum to match:

```
- hosts: host
  tasks:
    - name: Install package
      yum:
        name: <package_name>
        state: present
      register: result
      become: yes
      failed_when: '(result.msg | regex_replace("No package matching .* found available, installed or updated","")) != ""'
```